# SwiftUI: VStack in VStack, labels are truncated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue with SwiftUI. When I use multiple `VStack`s inside another `VStack`, I have strange issues with text truncating.

Here is the smallest reproducible example:

[image: VStacks inside VStack]

The "B" label is truncated, but it should not be. If I change the "A" text or the "B" text, by adding or removing some letters, the "B" label is sometimes buggy, sometimes ok.

[image: VStacks animation]

Here is the corresponding code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            }.background(Color.yellow)
            VStack {
                Text("BBBBBBBB")
                Text("CCC")
            }.background(Color.orange)
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Do I miss something or this is a bug of SwiftUI?

Thanks!

*Environment: Xcode 11.4.1, iOS 13.4.1, Tested on Previews, Simulator & Devices*

**Edit**: This behaves differently depending on the preview/simulator device you are using. For example, the above code, copy-pasted into a fresh project, is buggy on iPhone 11 Pro / 11 Pro Max and 8+. On iPhone 8 / 11 / SE 1&2, this works fine. So maybe it is related to some computational/rounding problems in the SwiftUI layout engine?

Comment: Can you check running the app once on simulator? I check one XCODE 11.3, it worked completely fine

Comment: @Manoj Same issue on simulators and devices. So maybe it's a regression of Xcode 11.4? Did you tried adding/removing some A and B?

Comment: Works fine for me on Xcode 11.4.1 and iOS 13.4.1

Comment: It does look like a bug. It happens only when you add/remove a character to come to total of 20.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Actually it does not seem to be related to the number of characters, but the width of the label. If you replace all uppercased letters (A, B and C) by their lowercased version (a, b, and c), the issue happens more often as your add/remove letters.

Comment: @Paulw11 Interesting... I did some tests, this seem to work if you use iPhone 8 / SE 1 & 2 / 11 as preview devices. With iPhone 11 Pro / 11 Pro Max / 8+, I have the issue.

Comment: @tdimeco Yeah, depends on some frame calculation.

Comment: It worked for me in on an 11pro, but then I tried different font sizes in settings; the bug only appears for the 3rd smallest size. All other size settings are fine.

Answer (score 2):

`.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` should fix it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                  .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            }.background(Color.yellow)
            VStack {
                Text("BBBBBBBB")
                   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                Text("CCC")
                   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            }.background(Color.orange)
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

For multilinetext: `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Swift enums are really powerful, but they can often be made even more capable when mixed with")
                  .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }.background(Color.yellow)
            VStack {
                Text("Swift enums are really powerful, but they can often be made even more capable when mixed ")
                   .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("Swift enums are really powerful, but they can often be made even more capable   ")
                   .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }.background(Color.orange)
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView2()
  }
}
```

Comment: This does fix the issue for 1-line labels, but does not for multi-lines labels. This is unfortunately not a solution for long texts like descriptions, and it is not compliant with Dynamic Types.

Comment: I updated my answer for multiline support. i am not sure what you mean with "compliant  with Dynamic Types" but if you have a Binding or State var it works just fine.

Comment: Ok not sure about Dynamic Types, haven't tested this yet. May you should update the question and code, when it is related more to Dynamic Type ...

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Seems to be fixed in SwiftUI 2 :)